# Selecting missing rows and grouping by date (with read-only access to DB)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset from which I need to count all row occurrences grouping by each day and sum them into a dataset of following format:

```
|     date     |  count  |
|  2001-01-01  |    11   |
|  2001-01-02  |    0    |
|  2001-01-03  |    4    |
```

The problem is, that some of the data is missing from certain periods of time and new dates should be created to have the count of zero. I have searched various topics considering this same issue and from them I've learned that it's possible to solve by creating a temporary calendar table to hold all the dates and join the result dataset with the date table.

Though, I have only a read access to the database I'm using, so it's not possible for me to create a separate calendar table. So could this be possible to solve in a single query only? If not, I could always do this in PHP but I would prefer a more straighforward way to do this.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify based on the questions asked in the comments: The missing dates are required for a spesific, user given time frame. E.g. the query could be:

```
SELECT date(timestamp), count(distinct(id)) 
FROM 'table' 
WHERE date(timestamp) BETWEEN date("2001-01-01") AND date("2001-12-31")
GROUP BY date(timestamp)
```

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11079061/1445836

Comment: Be specific, u want missing dates but between what period?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked here. Try searching for [`[mysql] missing dates`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+missing+dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is **really not made** for this kind of job :/

That's possible but really really messy and I **strongly** discourage you from doing it.

The easiest way was to have a separate calendar table but as you said you only have a read access to your database.

The other one is to generate the sequence using this kind of trick:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, ("yourquery") t;
```

I won't get into it, as I already told you, it's really ugly :(

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I already expected a little bit what you said that it wouldn't be possible (or at least trivial) to do this in SQL, but it's good that you pointed that out. I'll stick with PHP instead for processing the data into suitable format :)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*) Count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Date
```

This works for sure!!!

Let me know, if it helped!

Comment: No, [this does **not** work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8f7b/1). Your suggestion doesn't create missing dates, it only returns those that are present, nothing else.

Comment: ok u want missing too?? but then between which time period...?

Comment: Yes, the OP wants missing dates too. I don't know if they want them for a specific period or for an entire dataset. That's something you could ask in a comment to the original post.